# Error CSS in master layout - Zend Framework

Tags: css, zend-framework

Using the [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework), I have a menu and want to put it throughout the application so that I put it in the master layout.
I want to decorate the menu so I add a CSS as follow:

```
  echo $this->headScript()        
            ->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/css/layout.css');
```

In CSS it just have the following:

```
root { 
    display: block;
}
```

But when testing, [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28Firefox_extension%29) warn an error:

```
missing ; before statement
 root { \n
```

I checked the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) error but it's no problem.
All other CSS attached in the view script is work fine.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's Byte Order Mark (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would assume it's because you're using `$this->headScript()` so it's being evaluated as JavaScript rather than CSS! You should be using:

```
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl().'/css/layout.css');
```

Comment: Greate, it work well after I revised as your instruction.
Thank you